# Sharing ast between tsc and tslint

Tags: typescript, tslint

Is there a way to share the compiled AST between tsc and tslint or in other words can I integrate tslint in tsc? I'm strictly interested in the linting and type checking and not code generation itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you're thinking of is now doable in TypeScript as a [Language Service Plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin). See [typescript-tslint-plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript-tslint-plugin) for the TypeScript language service plugin for TSLint.